# Assignment of reactive value inside reactive statement got hoisted?

Tags: svelte-3

New to the Svelte community and try to understand the framework (compiler?).
So I tried the following code:
App.svelte:

```
<script>
    let count = 1;
    $: {
        console.log(`Before A: ${count}`);
        count = 2;
        console.log(`A: ${count}`);
    }
    $: {
        console.log(`B: ${count}`);
    }
    $: {
        console.log(`Before C: ${count}`);
        count = 3;
        console.log(`C: ${count}`);
    }
    $: {
        console.log(`D: ${count}`);
    }
</script>
```

A running prototype can be found [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/1d86959204874d3a9c814f07f54de922?version=3.35.0).

Please check find the output of the code from console.

Output:

```
"Before A: 1"
"A: 2"
"Before C: 2"
"C: 3"
"B: 3"
"D: 3"
```

It seems that the reactive statements including assignment of reactive value have been hoisted.

Is there any references about that behavior and explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Quote the answer by fs99 from discord:

> so basically all reactive statements run top-to-bottom, unless they depend on other reactive statements running first. In this case, A and C modify count, so A runs first, then C, then the others: again top-to-bottom, B and D.